# カレントディレクトリのファイル有無によってgrepコマンドの結果が異なる

Tags: bash, shellscript, sh

初歩的かもしれませんが、質問します。

例えば、

```
$ sed -n -e 10p ./hoge.txt | grep -o [0-9]*
```

のようにして、ファイルからある数値を抽出する際、
カレントディレクトリに 1111.pdf のようなファイルがあると
うまく抽出できません。（無いとうまく抽出できます）

なぜ、このような挙動になるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[0-9]*`がファイル名にマッチし

```
$ sed -n -e 10p ./hoge.txt | grep -o 1111.pdf
```

に展開されて`grep`が起動されています。展開を抑止したければ

```
$ sed -n -e 10p ./hoge.txt | grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

とすべきです。

Comment: いわゆる「パス名展開」というシェルの挙動を失念しておりました。ご教授ありがとうございました。